# Lithium: how to create admin module

Tags: lithium

I am new in lithium framework. I have did too much research about create module in lithium but unable to find working tutorial.

[Module based structure in Lithium](http://maximeparmentier.com/2011/06/17/module-based-structure-in-lithium/)

its not working tutorial please help me guys what's wrong in this tutorial

like following urls not in subdomain:

http://www.example.com/lithium/admin/user/login
http://www.example.com/lithium/admin/reports/delete

Comment: http://www.example.com/lithium/admin/user/login

http://www.example.com/lithium/admin/reports/delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach: https://github.com/jails/li3_bigbang

This structure allows for fully autonomic modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to configure admin (and other) routing for Li3: https://gist.github.com/nateabele/1512502